# Rearranging views when a view is removed using auto layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, layout, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewCell` like this.

[image]

All the required constraints are set properly and the cell resizes itself without an issue when the content changes in iOS 8 as well.

[image]

I have to hide the **Label 3** in certain conditions. When that happens I need to reposition **label 2** and the button closer like this.

[image]

I tried adding an extra vertical spacing constraint from label 2 to the button and set its Relation to Less Than or Equal.

[image]

And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I remove label 3 and updates the layout.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(InfoCell.identifier(), forIndexPath: indexPath) as InfoCell

    cell.label3.removeFromSuperview()
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()

    return cell
}
```

[image]

But as you can see the spacing between **label 2** and the button is still there.

Are there any more constraints I need to set or change any setting for existing constraints to get this working?

Comment: Hey, if the answer was unclear or didn't solve your problem can you comment, or mark it as accepted if it did? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "less than or equal to" constraint to be a normal constraint, set its value equal to the distance that you want to keep between the button and Label 2, and make it non-required by setting it to a lower priority than 1000.

By setting it to be a non-required constraint you won't get an unsatisfiable constraint conflict when Label 3 is included, and when you remove Label 3, the "non-required but high priority" constraint will kick in.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works but I have a new issue. I set the constraint back to equal and changed its priority to 749. I also set the constant to 10. When I run the app, the button increased its height to fill up that lost space like [this](http://i.imgur.com/3a27hX2.png). So I added a height constraint to the button to keep it fixed and then there is a space between label1 and label2 like [this](http://i.imgur.com/yOGSTz5.png).

Answer (score 1):

"Less than or equal" wouldn't do anything to compress the spacing--you probably meant for the space to be "greater than or equal to" the smallest possible spacing. If "less than" it could go down to zero.

"Greater than or equal" wouldn't work either: It's a constant source of confusion and frustration, because "greater than or equal to" does **not** mean "equal to, and greater than if it has to get bigger but only if it has to." Even if all other sizes are set, which is definitely not the case in an iOS8 self-sizing cell, Auto Layout doesn't fell any need to keep the size closer to the equals constant value; it's more to create a floor that other constraints can push above but not below. Auto Layout's thinking is "*You said 'greater than' and a million is greater than so i satisfied the constraints with a million dur dur*."

Removing a view removes any constraints attached to it to the view. As noted in the other answer, if you added a lower-priority constraint that linked View2 and button, it would break by priority if View3 is present, but kick in if View3 and its constraints are removed.

However, because the constraints are removed, you will have a problem when the View3 is removed and put back as part of the cell reuse process. You can either

1. Recreate constraints from scratch when putting View3 back, either in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `prepareForReuse`.
2. Save the constraints affecting View3 before you remove them (or all constraints in cell's contentView), maybe in a cell NSArray property, and restore before reuse.
3. Use a different reuseIdentifier if view3 is going to be removed, and check before dequeuing cell. Sending a message to nil does nothing, so repeating `[view3 removeFromSuperview]` should be fine.